# Is there a way to dispatch an action on Component Mount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I'm using Firebase for user authentication and I want to use the `onAuthStateChanged()` to make a user persist even after refreshing the browser. I'm also using redux-sagas to handle async operations.

Index.jsx file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import './App.scss';
import store from './store';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.jsx:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import routes from './routes';
import { actionTypes } from './components/signin/actionTypes';

const { VERIFY_REQUEST } = actionTypes;

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    VERIFY_REQUEST,
};

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    {routes.map(route => (
                        <Route
                            key={route.path}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            component={route.component}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

My sagas generator function binded to the action type:

```js
function onAuthState() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        loginToFirebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
                resolve(user);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Ops!'));
            }
        });
    });
}

function* verifyUserAuth() {
    try {
        const LOGIN_API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_AUTH_API;
        const { user } = yield onAuthState();
        console.log(user);
        const userInfo = { userAuth: user, userType: 'user' };
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
        const body = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
        const response = yield axios.post(LOGIN_API_URL, body, config);
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const { data: { info } } = response.data;
            yield put({ payload: info, type: VERIFY_SUCCESS });
        } else yield put(loginError(response.status));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(loginError(error));
    }
}

export default function* watchUserLoginAction() {
    yield takeEvery(VERIFY_REQUEST, verifyUserAuth);
}
```

Everytime I check my redux tools, I don't see the action being fired on component mount.

Comment: Have you tried using [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)?  its invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method whenever you want to do something **after** the component is mounted. Modify your `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
         return {
            verifyRequest: () => { dispatch( {type : VERIFY_REQUEST} ) }
          };
    };
```

and then call `verifyRequest` from `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.verifyRequest()
}
```

Also, it is better to create action creators instead of directly dispatching the action, like so

```
export const verifyRequestAction = () => {
    return {
        type: VERIFY_REQUEST
    }
}
```

and then

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
         return {
            verifyRequest: () => { dispatch(verifyRequestAction()}
          };
    };
```